# Averaging Plot values using for loop

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to average my plot(X,Y) data so that I get a smoother curve

the concept is of this fashion, which I can execute in the command window.

command window:

```
plot(X,Y) 
yold=y
plot(X,(Y+yold)/2.)
yold2=y
plot(X,(Y+yold+yold2)/3.)
```

I can do this from the comand window to get my curve smooth, but it would be very time consuming. Here is my code.

code:

```
plot(X,Y);
yoldy=0;
yold=0;
for av=1:100
    yoldy=yoldy+yold;
    plot(X,(Y+yoldy)/av);
    yold=Y;
end

plot(X,(Y+sum(yoldy)/101))
```

For some reason the graph looks the same, that is the plot un-averaged. Is it that my yoldy is not storing all the Y values at each stage?

This question was to address averaging values X in the program. This could simply be accomplished by adding a loop with the number times you want the program to be run, store each X values, and average them after each run. Then a smoother curve could be obtained. Sorry for not explaining properly.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to implement? Currently, you have implemented Y*av/av, which is Y and not an average.

Comment: what do you mean? I write (Y+yoldy)/av. I am not multiplying the Y.

Comment: I am trying to implement the same concept I was available to achieve in the command window plot(X,Y), yold=Y plot(X,(Y+yold)/2.)
yold2=Y, plot(X,(Y+yold+yold2)/3.), so becuase the Y values changes each time the program is run, I keep adding the previous Y values to the current Y value being plotted and average them. hence the plot(X,(Y+yold+yold2+yold3+.....+yoldav)/av.)

Comment: In your code, yoldy is `(av-1)*Y`. Thus `(Y+yoldy)/av=(Y+(av-1)*Y)/av=Y*av/av=Y`. Please describe which kind of average you are trying to implement, are you trying to implement a simple moving average?

Comment: No, simple moving average is droping of the previous values. when I do my plot(X,Y), if I should Plot(X,Y) again it will look similar, but not the same exact thing. because the Y changes. So I want my code to keep storing the Y values after each plot and adding them up each time along with the current Y value. but i do not want (av-1)*Y, if that is what my code is doing that is the problem

Comment: I want to get (Y+yoldy)/av, av is the number of loops and also the number of terms, so yoldy=yold+yold2+yold3+yold4...... and so on. after each plot I do yold=Y and update my sum storage of the Y values yoldy=yoldy+yold, so i keep adding Y to my yoldy then take the average and plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep a running sum and then divide by the # of values.  You could try this...

```
plot(x, y);
hold on;
plot(x, cumsum(y) ./ (1:length(y)), 'r');
```

Comment: that is exactly what i want!, that is a versatile and cheeky what to do things like it!